# Is there a way to have a Calendar Extender Restriction?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ajax

I have a calendar extendar issue that I seems tough for myself.  I am trying to restrict my nifty feature to display the current month and the month prior ONLY.  Is there anyone who can help with that? if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is an article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=149&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) (see tip 6) showing how to prevent a user from selecting a date greater than the current. You can probably see how to adapt it to work for your requirements.